# How and Where to add additional CSS to a hook in liferay

Tags: jquery, html, css, liferay, liferay-theme

I'm using Liferay 6.2 in my website .I need to restrict some class in my site. I wrote some CSS code in separate restrict.css file and import from main css. I used

```
@import url(restrict.css);
```

in my main CSS file. But i like to use those code with Liferay HOOK(.JSPF) file. Is this correct way to import css file to HOOK

```
<%@import url(/html/portlet/document_library/css/main.css)%>
```

I didn't see any changes

Any one know How to add CSS code or files in Liferay .jspf HOOKs

Comment: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/21118773

Comment: Thanks Parkash Kumar                                   
Is this correct way to import css file to HOOK
<%@import url(/html/portlet/document_library/css/main.css)%>
I didn't see any changes

Comment: If you adding it to jsp / jspf, then add css relationship like <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/html/portlet/document_library/css/main.css">